# PHP Block direct access to a file over but allow to only logged in owner of file

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, access-control

Edited : downl.php 
 Hi Royal Bg. 
I don't know how to thank you. But your code seems good but dificult to me to 
 understand so I still refere passing to download page....
My downl.php page looks like this:

```
 require('staff.php'); // User controll


if(($thisuser->getGroupId() != 4)){
    header('Location: index.php');
    require('index.php');  
    exit;
}
```

// Recieving student file id, student id and rums id (course id) From rum_st.php

```
if (isset($_GET['f-id']) && is_numeric($_GET['f-id']) && 
 $_GET['f-id'] >= 1 && isset($_GET['s-id']) && is_numeric($_GET['s-id']) && 
 $_GET['s-id'] >= 1 && isset($_GET['r-id']) && is_numeric($_GET['r-id']) && $_GET['r-id'] >= 1 ) {


 $file_id_s = $_GET['f-id'];
$stud_id = $_GET['s-id'];
$rums_id = $_GET['r-id'];



     $sql = " SELECT t.ticket_id, t.ticketID, t.staff_id, t.subject, r.rums_id, r.staff_id, r.rumsname ".
            " f.file1_id, f.rums_id, f.ticket_id, f.file_name, f.staff_id, f.filetype, f.filesize, f.created, f.dept_id ". // dept_id means class_id or grade_id
            " sc.school_id, sc.school_name ".
            " FROM ice_cust_ticket t ".
            " INNER JOIN ice_file f ON f.ticket_id = t.ticket_id ".

            " INNER JOIN ice_rums r ON r.rums_id = f.rums_id ".
            " INNER JOIN ice_cust_school sc ON sc.school_id = f.dept_id ". // school means class or grade

            " WHERE f.rums_id = ".$rums_id." " .
            " ORDER by f.created ";


     $res = mysql_query($sql);


 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {

    $filename = htmlspecialchars($row['file_name']);
    $fileID = $row['file1_id'];
    $rums_id3 = $row['rums_id'];
    $dept_id = $row['dept_id'];  // Class id if he/she is from class 4 .. 5 ..
    $dept_id3 = explode(',', $dept_id);

    if(in_array($thisuser->getdeptID(), $dept_id3)){


    $rumsname =  htmlentities($row['rumsname'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $file_name =  htmlentities($row['file_name'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $teacher_id = $row['staff_id'];

    // Teacher file
   // $target_path = "rums/".$teacher_id."/".$rumsname."/".$file_name."/";

   // Student file
    $target_path_st = "rums/".$teacher_id."/".$rumsname."/".$file_name."/".$thisuser->getId()."/";



    $sql_st_file = " SELECT * FROM ice_student_file WHERE file_id = ".$fileID." AND stud_id = ".$thisuser->getId()." ";
    $res_st = mysql_query($sql_st_file);
    $row_st = mysql_fetch_array($res_st);
    $file = $row_st['file_name'];
    $result = $row_st['result'];
    $opinion = $row_st['opinion'];


     // with link like target=_blank......
 //$url =  '<a href="'.$target_path_st.$file.'" target="_blank id="attached-file-link" style="text-decoration:none;">'.$file.'</a>'; 

   // or without link
   $url = '<a href="'.$target_path_st.$file.'">'.$file.'</a>';

   // this give me the same problem.. shows the link where it is and I have to click to download
   //echo $url;

   // echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';  // And This give me Error 403

    // The question is where to put the headers and what to write on headers...


    } 

    } 

    }
```

I’am creating simple system for my school with PHP.
Teachers  create their own course in a folder called rums
They can give access those courses to different classes. 
For example Teacher Linda create course with name Biology and give access to class 4 and 5. It’s works fine. 
So this will be localhost\my\my2\rums\ …and here creates folder with name Biology. But before Biology it creats one folder too with her user id nr for example Linda user id is  91 just to prevent conflict with other teachers course name. So it will be like following:
localhost\my\my2\rums\91\Biology 
Linda insert  downloadable files (like docx and pdf files ) in to this Biology folder who students from class 4 and 5 can download. Then they can insert different files to Linda to this folder as response to the homework so she can download students files too.
To this php page can only access those classes who have permission. And it works fine and they can see teachers file. 
So if student we say her name is Sarah from class 4 insert file to this folder he will just able to see her own inserted file.. and it works fine. No other can see it.
From database I get those files:

```
    $target_path_teacher_file = "rums/".$teacher_id."/".$rumsname."/".$file_name."/";
    $target_path_student_file = "rums/".$teacher_id."/".$rumsname."/".$file_name."/".$thisuser->getId

()."/";
```

And to show on a table I print out them like this:

```
<td><center><?php print '<a href="'.$ target_path_teacher_file.$filename.'" target="_blank id="attached-file-link" style="text-decoration:none;">'.$filename.'</a>'; ?></center></td>
<td><center><?php print '<a href="'.$target_path_student_file.$file.'" target="_blank id="attached-file-link" style="text-decoration:none;">'.$file.'</a>'; ?></center></td>
```

But  onmouseover over the files you can see the hole link where the files are.. and if David copy this link and send to other people and past it on web browser then even they can download his file and the teachers file too. 
So my dear people.. my question is how to prevent from downloading by other registered and none registered people except Sarah?  I tried with .htaccess file but didn’t work.
Any help you can give will be greatly appreciate. 
/ Jonas

[image]

Comment: privilleges/access control basing on directory structure is not good idea.

Comment: Are you storing users, rums, classrooms and files on a database?

Comment: Pep Lainez : Yes I do.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I can imagine on first look, without complicated directory permissions, is to have the file stored into a non-public directory:

i.e.:

```
www/private/assignment.docx
```

When you validate the user credentials, i.e. `Sarah` is from class 4 and one requests the file, run a script on the background that makes a temporary copy of the file to a public directory with different name i.e.

```
www/public/sarah-homework-2014-04-20.docx
```

And/or also don't give them the opportunity to know where the file comes from. Or at least make it harder. You don't need a direct link to it. Let your link lead to i.e. `download.php` with sent via session `user_id` and `file_id`.

Validate in download.php if this user_id has permissions and start downloading directly from `download.php`

---

You can also not allow downloading, but send them emails with the file. After successful validation that the user is from the allowed class, one can recieve email with the file attached.

---

All other ways I can imagine are file system permissions, .htaccess and so on.

---

About the question in the comments.

I would recommend using download via setting the proper content type header.
Open the file as resource, and force the download.

A simple user class where you have the userId, so you can check permissions (I will not check for permissions here, it's just an example)

```
class User {
    private $_id;
    public function setId($id) { $this->_id = $id; }
    public function getId() { return $this->_id; }
}
```

A simple class that gets the file info after recieving file_id;

```
class File {

    private $_directory;
    private $_filename;
    private $_id;

    public function setId($file_id) { 
        $this->_id = $file_id; 
        $this->getFileInfo();
        return $this;
    }

    private function getFileInfo() {
        $result = $this->getDb()->query("SELECT directory, filename FROM files WHERE id = {$this->getId()};");
        $row = $this->getDb()->fetch($result);
        $this->_directory = $row['directory'];
        $this->_filename = $row['filename'];
    }

    public function getDirectory() { return $this->_directory; }
    public function getFileName() { return $this->_filename; }
    public function getId() { return $this->_id; }

}
```

And then a download class. The download class recieves the instances of $user and $file. After setting the propert file_id and user_id, call the download class with these instances

```
class Download {

    private $_path;

    /**
     * @var File
     */
    private $_file;
    /**
     * @var User
     */
    private $_user;
    /**
     * @var Download
     */
    private $_size, $_info, $_ext, $_handle;
    private static $_inst = null;

    /**
     * 
     * @param User $user
     * @param File $file
     * @return Download
     */
    public static function init(User $user, File $file) {
        if (self::$_inst == null) {
            self::$_inst = new self();
            self::$_inst->_file = $file;
            self::$_inst->_user = $user;
            self::$_inst->setPath();
        }
        return self::$_inst;
    }
    /**
     * @return File
     */
    public function getFile() { return $this->_file; }
    /**
     *  @return User
     */
    public function getUser() { return $this->_user; }

    private function setPath() {
        $this->_path = $this->getFile()->getDirectory() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this->getFile()->getFileName();
    }

    public function getPath() { return __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$this->_path; }

    private function setFileInfo() {
        $this->_handle = fopen($this->getPath(), 'r');
            $this->_size = filesize($this->getPath());
            $this->_info = pathinfo($this->getPath());
            $this->_ext = strtolower($this->_info['extension']);

    }

    private function setHeaders() {
        switch ($this->_ext) {
            case '.docx':
                header("Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$this->_info['basename']."\"");
                break;
            case '.doc':
                header("Content-type: application/msword");
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$this->_info['basename']."\"");
                break;
            case '.txt':
                header("Content-Type:text/plain");
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$this->_info['basename']."\"");
                break;
            default;
                header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
                header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$this->_info['basename']."\"");
        }
        header("Content-length: $this->_size");
        header("Cache-control: private");
    }

    public function forceDownload() {
        $this->setFileInfo();
        $this->setHeaders();
        while(!feof($this->_handle)) {
            fread($this->_handle, 2048);
        }
        fclose($this->_handle);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Then you need something like

```
$user = new User();
$file = new File;

$user->setId(8);
$file->setId(3);
Download::init($user, $file)->forceDownload();
```

You can also not echo the basename of the file but something other, so you will not reveal its name aswell

Comment: Dear Royal Bg. Thank you for your time and your response. I'am not such good programer so I prefer direct link to Another page like download.php. I sent file_id, user_id and rums_id to downl.php and then wrote sql code to get path with rumsname teacher_id.. and so on. At last I get the path.. like $target_path_st = "rums/".$teacher_id."/".$rumsname."/".$file_name."/".$thisuser->getId()."/";  But how can  I oppen direct from downl.php . If I echo  '<a href="'.$target_path_st.$file.'" target="_blank id="attached-file-link" style="text-decoration:none;">'.$file.'</a>';  then it will be the same

Comment: @JonasWillander Use headers for this, but beware of the right headers. See my edit. Ofcourse there's a chance for the headers to be sniffed. But as long as you don't reveal the getPath() return value, they can only have the filename. You can not echo the basename but something else

Comment: @JonasWillander yep, ok :) so maybe you can just take the logic from my `forceDownload()`, `setFileInfo()` and `setHeaders()` methods in Download class. Maybe you don't need a class at all. Just use into your download page the file opening logic `if($handle = fopen($pathToFile)`, extract the size, pathinfo and extension, then set the proper headers for docx and that's it. You can also search in google for `force download php` maybe you will find something closer to this

Comment: I really tried to put my path and file name everywhere into your functions but been but I'am not enough to understand what I'am doing. You helped me all the way and  greatly appreciate. I know it's like "Do it for me" but can you please show me how to use and where to put my variables into the functions. You have all the data you need in my last edited, I'am sorry I'am so confused by this problem and I really need help. Thanks again Royal BG!

Comment: @JonasWillander Well, at least, you have written you code, not me, so I am not familiar with it, and it will be hard time for me to make your code compatible with mine. On the other hand, my code as standalone one, is working perfectly. I tested it with `New Folder/asdasd.txt` which was inserted into the database and the script goes to download it, when the ID is passed. This is the last I can do for you. Maybe you need to search for sample force download scripts in google in order to simplify then to fit your needs. :-)

Comment: you are right Mr. I realy to thank you for your time. God bless you.